How to change the restclient implementation for springai?
how can we change the RestClient Implementation for spring-ai?
We want to use the JdkClientHttpRequestFactory for testing or another implementation.
We tried to create a Bean for the restclient but this does not work.
thanks
Frank

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

here is our solution that worked:
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class AiConfig {

    @Value("${spring.ai.openai.api-key}")
    private final String openAiApiKey;

    @Bean
    OpenAiApi openAiApi() {
        final RestClient.Builder builder = RestClient.builder()
                .requestFactory(new JdkClientHttpRequestFactory());
        return new OpenAiApi(ApiUtils.DEFAULT_BASE_URL, openAiApiKey, builder);
    }

    @Bean
    ChatClient chatClient(OpenAiApi openAiApi) {
        return new OpenAiChatClient(openAiApi);
    }

    @Bean
    EmbeddingClient embeddingClient(OpenAiApi openAiApi) {
        return new OpenAiEmbeddingClient(openAiApi);
    }

